# MapStruct add a new calculated field to the dto

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mapstruct

I'm trying to map an entity `Order` to a `OrderDTO` using MapStruct. I want to add to `OrderDTO` a new field `total`, this field is not available in the original entity `Order` and should be calculated using the information available in the `Order` (order entries price, quantity, taxes...).
I created a new field `total` in the `OrderDTO` and I'm trying to map it by adding a default method to the mapper interface:

```
public interface OrderMapper {

    ...

    default BigDecimal orderToTotal(Order order){
        return logicToCalculateTotal();
    }
}
```

When I lunch the build MapStruct launch the error

> Unmapped target property: "total".

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve what you need. The first way is to use `@AfterMapping` or `@BeforeMapping`. If you go with this your code will look like:

```
public interface OrderMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "total", ignore = true) // Needed so the warning does not shown, it is mapped in calculateTotal
    OrderDto map(Order order);

    @AfterMapping // or @BeforeMapping
    default void calculateTotal(Order order, @MappingTarget OrderDto dto) {
        dto.setTotal(logicToCalculateTotal());
    }
}
```

The alternative approach would be to do like you started, but you have to say that `total` is mapped from the `Order`.

Your mapper in the alternative approach would be:

```
public interface OrderMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "total", source = "order")// the source should be equal to the property name
    OrderDto map(Order order);

    default BigDecimal orderToTotal(Order order) {
        return logicToCalculateTotal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you use these methods read carefully the relevant documentation: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.4/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after For example, in case of `@AfterMapping` you have to target the `@MappingTarget` to the return type builder.

Comment: From 1.6 you can also target the return type normally (in addition to being able to target the return type builder)

Answer (score 0):

**if the calculated field can be completely calculated by using other fields in DTO:**

I would put these calculations into getMethods - no need to add redundant fields. (Thinking about [tight cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)))

If you name the method `getTotal` it will be seen in json/xml with name "total" besides all other fields.