# Best practice to calculate an atribute in Jhipster design

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Let's imagine you create a Jhipster racing app where we have a Race class (id, raceName, date, List -Participant-, averageTime) which is made of Participant objects (which have an id and a racing time in seconds for each race). You would like to calculate the average time of the racing class as the times are released (as they cross the finish line) and everytime a race is consulted. For that, where would you put the method for calculating such an average?

I see 3 options:

1. In the view of your angular class when you show your Race component you can bring data and calculate it each time it is shown.
2. Somewhere in the Race Service Implementation.
3. In the domain model with a @Transient when the Race object is instanciated

Please, if you see another options or a best practice let me know. Thanks

> entity Race {     raceName String,
> time Instant,
> averageTime Double }
>
> entity Participant {
> racingTime Integer }
>
> relationship OneToMany {  Race{participant(id)} to
> Participant{race(id)} }
>
> // SET PAGINATION OPTIONS: paginate all with pagination // paginate
> ChatMessage with infinite-scroll // paginate all with infinite-scroll
>
> // SET SERVICE OPTIONS: service all with serviceImpl //service all
> with serviceClass
>
> // DTO: dto all with mapstruct
>
> // FILTERING: filter *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference is to do this in the service layer as part of the conversion from domain model to DTO. You could implement a `@Transient` getter in the `Race` domain model which calculates the average and (I think) mapstruct could map this across to the DTO. Or you could just set the extra DTO field in your service method(s).
There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500779/mapstruct-add-a-new-calculated-field-to-the-dto/45511193) where you can put the calculation in your mapper.

Comment: Thanks Hopey. Do you mean here: (https://github.com/Tonterias/mapstruct/blob/222c03cf4b4d7d641f05e803dbb31ad077554c20/src/main/java/com/junit/test/service/impl/RaceServiceImpl.java#L46) if you can tell me where, I will appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: Hopey, imagine that I do not use MapStruct and the DTO. Where would you place it then? Thanks again.

Comment: @JorgeM.Nures, yep that is where I would do it. You would need to add it everywhere you want it to be in the DTO (maybe the `save` and `findOne` as well). If you're not using DTOs/services then I guess you need that transient field in your entity and either the populate it before it gets converted to JSON or calculate it on the fly in a getter and hopefully Jackson would put it in the JSON.

Comment: Hi @Hopey One, I tried to figure out how to do it, but I guess I have no clue about how to work with those DTO in Jhipster and I could not find any example on how to do it. Could you help me out? Thanks

Comment: I have found a great tutorial here: https://stackabuse.com/data-transfer-object-pattern-in-java-implementation-and-mapping/